# Why the function parameter is omitted?

Tags: objective-c

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)onClick:(id)sender{
    self.label.text=@"HelloWorld";
    NSLog(@"%@",self.label.text);
}
```

When the `onClick` function called as a parameter, why the `(id)sender` is omitted? Such as `@selector(onClick:sender)`.

Comment: forgive me my poor English...

Comment: Because in Objective-C, `sender` is the parameter, it's not in the signature. `@selector()` awaits for the signature. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW8

Comment: It awaits a selector, not a signature, what is something different and would include the `id` part.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C methods are executed via messages. Basically when a message is received, the method with the same selector is executed.

The selector ("method name") contains all parts of the method except the name of the parameter variables and its types. Therefore the method …:

```
-(void)doSomethingWith:(id)this and:(id)that { … }
```

… has the selector `doSomethingWith:and:`. Nothing else.

The button needs this information to build up a message. It does not need information about the parameter names and its classes for an object parameter.  These information is completely removed at compile time. (To be honest it is not, but there is no *official*  API to get it.)

To the comment: The *signature* is exactly the other part. It contains the type information for parameters. But as said for objects of all classes it is simply `@`, what means "object".